# Count Reoccurrence Method

Tags: java, file, methods, count

I have a program that takes a list of names from an input file (input.txt) and displays them all correctly in alphabetical order. What I am now trying to do is count all the times each first and last name appears in the file and display that tally. I have a `countOccurrence` method and also how I tried to use it in the main method shown in the code below. The method keeps giving me errors and I need help trying to fix it so I can run the program and use it to count. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
{
    public class Names {

        public static void display(ArrayList<String> names) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
            }
        }

        public static int find(String s, ArrayList<String> a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i = i + 1) {
                String str = a.get(i);
                if (str.equals(s)) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> names) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
                String name = names.get(i);
                if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                    String firstLetter = "" + name.charAt(0);
                    names.set(i, firstLetter.toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }

        public static void sort(ArrayList<String> names) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size() - 1; i = i + 1) {
                int Min = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < names.size(); j = j + 1) {
                    if (names.get(j).compareTo(names.get(Min)) < 0) {
                        Min = j;
                    }
                }
                String tmp = names.get(i);
                names.set(i, names.get(Min));
                names.set(Min, tmp);
            }
        }

        public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn, ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the input flie?");
            String names = kb.next();
            File inpFile = new File(names);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String firstName = in.next();
                String lastName = in.next();
                fn.add(firstName);
                ln.add(lastName);
            }
        }

        private int countOccurence(String name,ArrayList<String> names){
            int count = 0;
            for(int i =0; i <= names.size; i++){
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(names.get(i))){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
            getNames(first, last);
            capitalize(first);
            capitalize(last);

            ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
                allNames.add(last.get(i) + ", " + first.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("*******All Names******");

            sort(allNames);
            display(allNames);

            System.out.println("*****First Name Count***");

            for(int i =0; i <= first.size; i++){
                int count = countOccurence(first.get(i), first);
                System.out.println(first.get(i) + " occured " + count + " times.");
            }

            System.out.println("****Last Name Count****");

            sort(last);
            display(last);
        }
```

In the method it gives an error in the for loop saying " size has private access in ArrayList". Then in the main method at the function call it gives another error saying " non static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: What are the errors?  Which line gives the errors?  Are they compiler errors or runtime errors?

Comment: @phflack  In the actual method it gives an error in the for loop saying " size has private access in ArrayList". Then in the main method at the function call it gives another error saying " non static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: @phflack okay thank you. I'll try it and let you know what happens

Comment: @phflack : Put those errors you mention in the comments as part of the question, so that it is complete.

Comment: @WhirlMind I mostly just moved it to answers to be more readable, and that's where answers belong, or do you mean putting Kevin's errors in the question instead of as comments?

Comment: @phflack I got a couple errors in the compiler. I listed them under your answer

Comment: Also note that your code in `public static int find(String s, ArrayList<String>a)` can be replaced with just using `a.indexOf(s);`.  Looking into the new errors now

Comment: @phflack so if I use the alternative method. How could I use it in the main? Because I'm still getting errors in the compiler

Comment: @phflack nevermind I fixed a couple things and its working find for now. Thank you so much, is there anyway I can contact you if I need other help?

Comment: @KevinPaz Updated my profile to have a bit more contact info, normally the fastest way to reach me is on [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/id/phflack/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `first.size` in your for loop.  Since you're using a List, you must use the `first.size()` method of your ArrayList

---

Your second issue is calling `private int countOccurence()` from your static main method, which means that you must make it be `private static int countOccurence()`

The `static` keyword is used when a method/variable is shared between all instances of the class and does not rely on any specific instance of the class.  In this case, it just takes an input and provides an output and so it may be `static`, along with the rest of your methods

---

Your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by an off by one error, you're reading one too far in your for loop

In your `countOccurence` method, your for loop is going one too far, change

```
for(int i = 0; i <= names.size; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
```

alternatively you can use a foreach loop instead and not have to deal with the counter, and not risk going out of bounds

```
private static int countOccurence(String name,ArrayList<String> names)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(String s : names)
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: So I ran it and got a few different errors now.  *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 18, Size: 18  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)  at names.Names.countOccurence(Names.java:84)  at names.Names.main(Names.java:111) Java Result: 1*

Comment: @KevinPaz Updated with what's causing your out of bounds exception